# Open a Dialog box in the same position as of the Main Form in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have to open **AboutForm** in WPF as Dialog box in the same position on top of the MainForm when I clicked on **Button1** in **MainForm**. Below code works fine if I open the form using **Show()** method but when I use **ShowDialog()** the form opens in the centre of the screen. I have tried with some other options too such as setting **Owner** property of AboutForm and **WindowStartupLocation** but non worked for me. Could you please help me how to open a Dialog box at the same position on top of the form?

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                    AboutForm aboutForm = new AboutForm();
                    aboutForm .Show();
                    aboutForm .Left = this.Left;
                    aboutForm .Top = this.Top;
            }
```

Comment: What was your problem with `Owner` and `WindowStartupLocation`? This should normally work.

Comment: @nosale It was my mistake. There was WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" in the .xaml file and the values What I set in the CodeBehind never reflected and the ShowDialog() always opens in the centre of the screen. However, Show() method opens in the same position as I set in the CodeBehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the window properties before calling the ShowDialog() method.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var aboutForm = new AboutForm
    {
        Width = Width,
        Height = Height,
        Left = Left,
        Top = Top,
        Owner = this
    };

    aboutForm.ShowDialog();
}
```